# How service id is derived from ed25519 key?

Tags: onion-services

What's the exact algorithm and where is it specified in documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding of the onion service address is specified in section 6 of the rendezvous specification: https://github.com/torproject/torspec/blob/master/rend-spec-v3.txt#L2136

> The onion address of a hidden service includes its identity public key, a
> version field and a basic checksum. All this information is then base32
> encoded as shown below:
>
> ```
> onion_address = base32(PUBKEY | CHECKSUM | VERSION) + ".onion"
> CHECKSUM = H(".onion checksum" | PUBKEY | VERSION)[:2]
> ```
>
> where:
>
> - `PUBKEY` is the 32 bytes ed25519 master pubkey of the hidden service.
> - `VERSION` is an one byte version field (default value `\x03`)
> - ".onion checksum" is a constant string
> - `CHECKSUM` is truncated to two bytes before inserting it in onion_address